# fake ajax calls with sinonjs

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, sinon

I'm trying to automate end to end testing with protractor and I'm using sinonjs to setup a fakeServer to respond to certain ajax calls (not all) which are triggered by button clicks.

I'm stuck and not sure how to go about it and being a novice in automation I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
describe("SinonFakeServerTest", function() {
    var fakeServer;
    beforeEach(function () {
        fakeServer = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        fakeServer.autoRespond = true;

        var data = {key1: 'xyz', key2: 'abc'};
        var response = [ 200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, data ];
        fakeServer.respondWith( '/abc/xyz/*', response );
    }

    afterEach(function () {
        fakeServer.restore();
    }

    it("should fake a ajax request", function () {
        // click on this button triggers ajax call..
        element(by.css('.take-button')).click();
        //should show fake data on ui
    });
});
```

This is the production code for button click controller and model

```
'.take-button click' : function(el, ev) {
    model.getData(listParams, this.proxy('setUpData'));
},

getList : function(params, success) {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/abb/xyz/getAll.htm',
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "GET",
        data : {
            params : params
        },
        success : success
    });
}
```

Comment: Show your production code

Comment: @luboskrnac - i have added the code that is executed on button click..thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't successfully fake server with Sinon's `fakeServer` feature when production code was using JQuery for AJAX calls.

I would suggest to try plain Sinon stubbing for `$.ajax`. There is actually example on [sinonjs.org](http://sinonjs.org) site (look into section `Testing Ajax`):

```
after(function () {
    // When the test either fails or passes, restore the original
    // jQuery ajax function (Sinon.JS also provides tools to help
    // test frameworks automate clean-up like this)
    jQuery.ajax.restore();
});

it("makes a GET request for todo items", function () {
    sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax");
    getTodos(42, sinon.spy());

    assert(jQuery.ajax.calledWithMatch({ url: "/todo/42/items" }));
});
```

Comment: what im trying to achieve is to send custom http response on button clicks.. does stub achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue in protractor without sinonjs.
I used mockjax to hack selected ajax calls and injected this script through browser.executeScript()